# how to svn add files under version control?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i have svn setup on my server: `/home/svn/setup`

i also have the files that i want them under svn control here: `/var/www/html/trunk`

how do i get the files from `/var/www/html/trunk` under version control inside `/home/svn/trunk` ??

if i run `svnadmin verify /home/svn/setup/` i get `* Verified revision 0.`

`setup` is where i have svn installed. im thinking to ad the website file in another folder called `trunk`

any ideas?

THnaks

edit: if i do `svn import /var/www/html/trunk file:///home/svn/trunk -m 'Initial import'

i get `svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/svn/trunk'`
`

Comment: It looks like you should spend some time working through the tutorials on SVN in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). There's a free online version - these are very basic operations, and are covered quite well in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to checkout the svn repository into a [*working copy*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.basic.working-copy), in your case `/var/www/html/trunk` (with `svn checkout`). Then, add the files and `commit`.

By the way, is there a reason why you're using svn on the local filesystem? A distributed version control system such as mercurial or git is faster, more scalable, and easier to setup to boot. For reference, with mercurial, you'd have just to type `hg init` in `/var/www/html/trunk`, and that would suffice to setup the repository.

Answer (score 0):

That means /home/svn/trunk is not where your initial repository is located. You have svn setup, but did you create a repository?